# Link of class "*.*" failed in Eclipse?

Tags: android, adt, ads, adwhirl

I try to integrate AdWhirl into my app. I do everything from the Internet and nothing success now. It just shows

```
10-07 16:25:42.183: I/dalvikvm(628): Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/MdotMAdapter;
 interface 1374 'Lcom/mdotm/android/ads/MdotMView$MdotMActionListener;'
 10-07 16:25:42.183: W/dalvikvm(628): Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/MdotMAdapter;' failed
```

I checked Android Dependencies in Java Build Path, did remove/add all jar in libs folder, but still no luck at all.
Could you give me some advices?

My system info:

Eclipse Helios 3.7.

ADT r20.

Testing device: Emulator 2.3.3.

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope solution will be founded

Answer (score 2):

try to use cleanup from source in eclipse
Right click project >> source>> cleanup